# Summary row or dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have a summary row of the below table. Result will be unique count of member ID, sum of receipts, and sum of spending. But the only way I can think of is creating a new column with same value, and using the same value column to do a groupby aggregate function to get the result. Is there a simpler way?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Mbr ID':['ID0001','ID0002','ID0003','ID0004'],
                 'Receipts':[3,5,12,5],                 
                 'Spending':[130,22,313,46],
                 })
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `df['Mbr ID'].nunique(), df.Receipts.sum(), df.Spending.sum()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add new summary row by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) of column `Mbr ID` and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) of columns `Receipts` and `Spending`:

```
df.loc['Summary'] = [df['Mbr ID'].nunique(), df.Receipts.sum(), df.Spending.sum()]
print (df)  
         Mbr ID  Receipts  Spending
0        ID0001         3       130
1        ID0002         5        22
2        ID0003        12       313
3        ID0004         5        46
Summary       4        25       511
```

If need `index` of new row same as previous one increments by 1:

```
df.loc[df.index[-1] + 1] = [df['Mbr ID'].nunique(), df.Receipts.sum(), df.Spending.sum()]
print (df)  
   Mbr ID  Receipts  Spending
0  ID0001         3       130
1  ID0002         5        22
2  ID0003        12       313
3  ID0004         5        46
4       4        25       511
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```
df.groupby('Mbr ID').agg({
        'Mbr ID': 'count', 
        'Receipts': 'sum', 
        'Spending': 'sum'})

#         Mbr ID  Spending  Receipts
# Mbr ID                            
# ID0001       1       130         3
# ID0002       1        22         5
# ID0003       1       313        12
# ID0004       1        46         5
```